# Is it more intensive to change database or open a new connection?

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I am using PHP to connect to MySQL. I am connected and have selected a certain database where 99.9% of my data resides.

If I wanted to pull something from a second database, residing on the same server.

Is it faster/less resource-intensive to open up a new, second connection to MySQL and select the second database, or am I better off changing to that database at the time I need the data, then changing back to resume the normal flow?

Comment: make a user with access privileges to both databases and connect once. Select the data you need using `database.table.column` . making new connections every time you change a database is more expensive

Comment: … and would also count against the number of max. open connections if you’re not closing the first one.

Comment: Do you want to submit as an answer @SamD so I can accept? Sounds reasonable to me and that is what I suspected. If you could give an example in actual PHP/SQL that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment you can give user permission to use both databases and run queries between databases with `database.table.column` syntax

For example the following query JOINS two tables in two databses and displays customer name and username:

```
SELECT C.name, U.username
FROM db1.Customers AS C
JOIN db2.Users AS U ON U.id = C.user_id
```

making new connections every time is more expensive

Comment: Ah that's great - I didn't know you could change databases like that (i.e. database.table.column)! How have I gone this long without knowing that? lol